# Change DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemSource based on the DataGrid Item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

In my application I am using C#, WPF and I am following the MVVM pattern.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

I have a `DataGrid`, which `ItemSource` is bounded on `Collection<MyObject>` in my ViewModel. `MyObject` has two `enum` properties, TypeA and TypeB (TypeA is a different enum type than TypeB).

```
enum TypeA {one, two, three}
enum TypeB {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
```

Each row of the `DataGrid`, has a `ComboBox` where the user can change the TypeB values by choosing one of the available value. User can not change TypeA. However the available values of TypeB are base on the value of TypeA.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type B">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding TypeB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DescriptionConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
             </ComboBox>
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Let's say the the available TypeB values can be found using the following rule:

> If Type = one then TypeB available values are {a,b,c,d}
>   If Type = two then TypeB available values are {d, e, f, g}
>   If Type = three then TypeB available values are {a, b, f, g}

I am trying to replicate this logic to the DataGrid and I followed the approaches below. However some of them do not work and other 'break' the MVVM pattern. Any thoughts or suggestions?

1. Bind ComboBox to a `dynamic` ItemSource
   So in my combobox I have something like

   ```
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TypeBAvailable}"
   ```

   and in view model

   ```
   public ICollectionView AvailableTypeB
   {
       get
       {
           ObservableCollection<TypeB> availableTypeB = new ObservableCollection<TypeB>((TypeB[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeB)));

           // Here based on the TypeA property of the SelectedRow in the grid 
           // I am populating the availableTypeB collection with the needed values based on the aforementioned rules

           return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(availableTypeB);
       }
   }
   ```

   *`SelectedRow` is an item that is bounded to the DataGrid's SelectedItem.

   I also tried instead of creating every time the collection and returning the default view, to create one time a CollectionView for the TypeB enum items and each time to apply a new `Filter` based on the `SelectedRow`

   The problem with this approach was that the SelectedItem of ComboBox was null, when the AvailableTypeB was changing and the SelectedItem was not part of it anymore. I tried to variate the binding `Mode` and the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` but with no luck.
2. The second approach I tried was to fill the ComboBox.ItemsSource on ComboBox.Loaded event. This can be implemented with several ways, what I tried was

   -. Having a Loaded event and do `ComboBox.ItemsSource =` in the code behind

   -. Using the Interactivity reference in order to have a command instead of the loaded event.

   Both of them, 'break' somewhat the MVVM pattern. When using the Interactivity assembly, I had to pass the `ComboBox` control to the model in order to access its data source, which a direct violation of MVVM

   I am aware that there is a third approach, which is using attached behaviours that I haven't tried yet.
3. Put the Collection of available TypeB values as a only-get property in my `MyObject` class. This is the cleaner solution, however it makes my `MyObject` class less generic. There are parts of my program where the user can change the `TypeB` value where the aforementioned rules do not apply and this is why I would like to avoid this approach.

**Note 1:** Since this is a long post, I tried to keep the code samples to minimum. If you think that some details are missing, please ask them and I will edit / update.
**Note 2:** I understand that some parts of the question may be 'opinion based' and maybe codeReview is a better place for it.

Comment: I suggest you do as in your option 3, call it `TypeBListFiltered` or something (filter based on a `SelectedTypeA` property), and expose a separate full TypeB list as `TypeBList`. Consumers use whichever list is appropriate. That's not "less generic". But you could also write a valuecoverter which takes a single parameter of TypeA, and returns a filtered collection of TypeB values. Your option 2 is a bad idea, as you know. A fil

Comment: @EdPlunkett To tell the truth I like the converter (i thought it also but I did not mentioned). However my opinion is that converters are not intended to be used this way. As they name implies, they are converting values and not filtering them. From another point of view you can say that filtering is a type of conversion.

Comment: True, you usually think of converters converting scalar values, not converting an unfiltered collection into a filtered one. But with a small constant collection it doesn't strike me as an abuse of the mechanism. It won't create any ugly surprises and it won't swamp you at runtime. And if I see `ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTypeA, Converter={StaticResource TypeBFilterConverter}}"`, I won't have to waste any time guessing what I'm looking at.